# Entity Framework and Encrypted Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, encryption

I have a column (salary) encrypted in database (MS SQL Server). 
I am using the entity framework  to display/edit the records from the front end. Any idea how to decrypt the column in the front end to show the salary value?

Thanks

Comment: What type of encryption do you use? MD5?
Some encryption types cant be decrypted.

Comment: I am using the TRIPLE_DES ENCRYPTION - http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/28/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-encryption-and-symmetric-key-encryption-tutorial-with-script/

Comment: How did you encrypt it? use the same class to decrypt it. It probably has decryption functions implemented, if it's a symmetrical encryption.

Comment: I am doing encryption at the database level. Please see the link in my previous comment

Comment: So just use a 3DES class that decrypts the data prior to displaying it, you probably know the key since someone must've set it (if not the encryption is useless)... see [this](http://blog.950buy.com/article/php-and-net-common-encryption-and-decryption-function-class-use-of-3des-encryption-and-decryption/) link

Comment: @chuber MD5 is not an encryption algorithm, it is a hash function.

Comment: @Shai: why don't you post that as an asnwer, so it gets the proper credit it deserves?

Comment: @RemusRusanu, Ladislav's answer is probably better... :-)

Comment: @Shai: you cannot decrypt SQL Server encrypted data in the client, even if you know the key. SQL Server adds additional information to the data (a header which contains, among other things, the key salt/IV) which is not publickly documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing encryption on database level you must use database level for decryption - use `ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<YourEntityType>(...)` to load records from database - pass SQL command with correct decryption usage into that method.

Comment: ... and the correct decryption function is [`DECRYPTBYKEY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181860.aspx)